# ¡Como puedo imprimir el objeto siguiente de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Como puedo imprimir el un objeto siguiente de un arrayList estoy usando hashtable.

pero tengo dudas este el punto que me toca resolver:
Dado el objeto que representa una persona, retornar el objeto que representa la persona del mismo estrato que fue agregada después

Tengo el siguiente metodo agregar

```
public void Agregar(Persona persona) {
        personas.put(persona.getCedula(), persona);
    }
```

tengo la clase main agregados los siguentes objetos

```
 Eps eps = new Eps();
        eps.Agregar(new Persona("1234", "Andres", "Perez", 1, 2));
        eps.Agregar(new Persona("4321", "Pedro", "Barreto", 3, 2));
        eps.Agregar(new Persona("3241", "Maria", "Vargas", 2, 1));
        eps.Agregar(new Persona("4556", "Camila", "Baron", 2, 1));
        eps.Agregar(new Persona("2434", "Fernanda", "Corso", 2, 1));
        eps.Agregar(new Persona("3433", "Andrea", "Rincon", 2, 1));
```

y estos objetos los agregaria a un arrayList, pero como retornaria el objeto siguiente del arrayList no se si me hice entender

Comment: Y el estrato cúal es?

Comment: @Lobos visualmente seria la columna 4 donde el valor empieza en 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego ejemplo comentado.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1. crear un LinkedHashMap
    // el LinkedHashMap mantiene los elementos ordenados según se insertan
    // esto es importante para poder recuperar la siguiente perso
    LinkedHashMap<String, Persona> personas = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // 2. agregar algunas personas
    Persona p1 = new Persona("1234",2);
    personas.put(p1.cedula, p1);

    Persona p2 = new Persona("343",3);
    personas.put(p2.cedula, p2);

    Persona p3 = new Persona("342342",2);
    personas.put(p3.cedula, p3);


    Persona siguientePersona = buscarSiguientePersona(p1.cedula, personas);

    if(siguientePersona != null){
        System.out.println("persona encontrada");
    }



}

public static  Persona buscarSiguientePersona(String cedula, Map<String, Persona> personas){

    // 3. buscar la siguiente persona agregada después de la persona p1
    // que tenga su mismo estrato

    // esta variable permite saber cual persona es la que se desea recuperar
    int estrato = -1;

    // aqui se almacenará la persona si se encuentra
    Persona siguientePersona = null;

    // iterar el Map
    for (Map.Entry<String, Persona> entry : personas.entrySet()) {
        // si estrato es diferente a -1 es porque ya se encontró a la persona p1
        // y ahora se buscará a la siguiente persona insertada que tenga su mismo
        // estrato
        if (estrato != -1) {

            if(entry.getValue().estrato == estrato){
                // si el estrato coincide recuperar la persona
                // y terminar la búsqueda
                siguientePersona = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
            // si no coincide continuar
            continue;
        }

        // si el valor de la cedula de la persona actual coincide con el de la persona
        // p1 entonces la variable estrato tendrá el valor de estrato actual
        // que servirá para buscar a la siguiente persona del mismo estrato
        // insertada después de esta
        if(entry.getValue().cedula.equals(cedula)){
            estrato = entry.getValue().estrato;
        }


    }
    return siguientePersona;
}

static class Persona {
    String cedula;
    int estrato;

    Persona(String cedula, int estrato) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.estrato = estrato;
    }


}

}
```